# Using Subquery in ORDER BY clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I got a few tables i want to join together.

The first script is the following

```
SELECT 
    Project_Assignment.ID_Project,
     MIN(Project_Assignment.ID_Workstep) as orderme  // this field i removed for mysql field() function
FROM
    ProjectBoard.Project_Assignment
WHERE
    Project_Assignment.isDone = 0
GROUP BY Project_Assignment.ID_Project
ORDER BY MIN(Project_Assignment.ID_Workstep)
```

and it returns

```
| ID_Project | orderme |
| 12         | 1       |
| 8          | 2       |
| 11         | 4       |
| 16         | 9       |
```

My second query is like

```
SELECT 
    Workstep_Content.ID_Project,
    Workstep_Content.ID_Step,
    Workstep_Content.Content
FROM
    ProjectBoard.Workstep_Content
```

and returns

```
| ID_Project | ID_Step | Content    |
| 11         | 11      | one        |
| 11         | 12      |another one |
| 12         | 1       |  two       |
| 8          | 11      | this       |
| 16         | 1       | first      |
| 16         | 4       | second     |
```

Now I want to order the results of my second query by their order of ID_Project in the first query.
The result should look like:

```
| ID_Project | ID_Step | Content    |
| 12         | 1       |  two       |
| 8          | 11      | this       |
| 11         | 11      | one        |
| 11         | 12      |another one |
| 16         | 1       | first      |
| 16         | 4       | second     |
```

I tried something with the MySQL [FIELD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_field.asp) function in the ORDER BY clause but it dint worked (`ORDER BY FIELD(ID_Project,first_query)`

Comment: JOIN the two tables, then aggregate and sort?  Or, JOIN the content table to your first query?

Comment: To my knowledge, `ORDER BY` only follows numeric and lexicographic ordering. To  achieve what you're after, you could add an artificial column to the results of your first query and number the results 1,2,3,... Give this column an alias such as `ORDER_ID`. Then in the join query, `ORDER_BY firstresult.ORDER_ID`.

Comment: @MatBailie I tried to join the to querys but I could not get any further when in the first query 2 ID_Projects got the same orderme

Comment: @h0r53 thank you i will try this approach how did i not think of it myself

Comment: Please tell what you really tried, and not "I tried something with ....but it dint worked" ... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join with the subquery, then use `ORDER by orderme`

```
SELECT 
    w.ID_Project,
    w.ID_Step,
    w.Content
FROM
    ProjectBoard.Workstep_Content AS w
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        Project_Assignment.ID_Project,
         MIN(Project_Assignment.ID_Workstep) as orderme  // this field i removed for mysql field() function
    FROM
        ProjectBoard.Project_Assignment
    WHERE
        Project_Assignment.isDone = 0
    GROUP BY Project_Assignment.ID_Project
) AS o ON w.ID_Project = o.ID_Project
ORDER BY o.orderme
```

Answer (score 2):

How I'd do it...

```
SELECT 
    wc.ID_Project,
    wc.ID_Step,
    wc.Content
FROM
    ProjectBoard.Workstep_Content   AS wc
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        ID_Project,
        MIN(ID_Workstep) as orderme
    FROM
        ProjectBoard.Project_Assignment
    WHERE
        isDone = 0
    GROUP BY
        ID_Project
)
    AS pa
        ON pa.ID_Project = wc.ID_Project
ORDER BY
    pa.orderme,
    wc.ID_Step
```

How others may do it...

```
SELECT 
    wc.ID_Project,
    wc.ID_Step,
    wc.Content
FROM
    ProjectBoard.Workstep_Content   AS wc
INNER JOIN
    ProjectBoard.Project_Assignment AS pa
        ON pa.ID_Project = wc.ID_Project
WHERE
    pa.isDone = 0
GROUP BY
    wc.ID_Project,
    wc.ID_Step,
    wc.Content
ORDER BY
    MIN(pa.ID_Workstep),
    wc.ID_Step
```

How anarchists may do it...

```
SELECT 
    wc.ID_Project,
    wc.ID_Step,
    wc.Content
FROM
    ProjectBoard.Workstep_Content   AS wc
ORDER BY
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(ID_Workstep)
        FROM
            ProjectBoard.Project_Assignment
        WHERE
                ID_Project = wc.ID_Project
            AND isDone     = 0
    ),
    wc.ID_Step
```